# Visual Studio regex or macro to turn block of code into one-liner

Tags: regex, visual-studio, macros

Is there a way in the Visual Studio editor to reformat a block of code - e.g. properties or any other mulitline block of code - into a one-liner? I have the Text Editor setting to 'Leave block on single line', but while it may *keep* code on single line it does not *reformat* to a single line on Format Document/Selection. I have tried Replace using various regex patterns, and it may find the line endings, but I can't get it to delete it (\n and subsequent whitespace on the following line) and move the following line up.

I would like a tip on how to reformat this:

```
public int Age 
{ 
  get 
  { 
    return age; 
  } 
}
```

into this one-liner:

```
public int Age { get { return age; } }
```

Anyone really good with macros or Replace using regex pattern?

Comment: could you post the regex you tried?

Comment: Would probably do this in a couple of steps. 1) Replace new lines with a single space. 2) Remove duplicate whitespace.

Comment: Stumbled upon this tool which does the trick:
http://www.codemaid.net/documentation/#joining

Answer (score 1):

Here's an ugly regex solution:

Replace this pattern:

```
^(\s*(?:(?:public|private|protected|internal|static|virtual|override|new)\s+)\S+\s+\S+)[\s\r\n]*\{[\s\r\n]*get[\s\r\n]*\{\s*(return\s+.+;)[\s\r\n]*\}[\s\r\n]*\}
```

With this:

```
$1 { get { $2 } }
```

For some reason VS seems to *not* include `[\r\n]` in `\s` as it should.

But since this solution is ugly, you should know that [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) can reformat your code easily (with iths code cleanup feature) and is highly customizable.

Comment: Granted, works for this specific piece of code (in VS2013, not in VS2010). But I'm looking for a more general solution to concatenate *any* block into one line. This regex fails if the code deviates slighly, e.g if the property has a setter. Thanks for the effort, though.

Comment: It's easy to expand upon if the property has a setter. If you need a general solution, well... there's ReSharper ;)